# How do I select a unique column value and display its sum of values of another column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to select the sum of `NumberOfHours` for the person with `PNr = 19900130`. I want the `PNr` to be unique but show PNr column = 19990130 and a column of the sum of that persons number of hours. What's the trick?

```
PNr         Date       NumberOfHours
----------  ----------  -----------
19990130    20200301    8
20100003    20200204    9
19990130    20200530    10
19990130    20200808    7
19990130    20200507    10
19990130    20200209    8
19990130    20200702    4
19990130    20200606    6
19990130    20201212    6
19990130    20200909    3
19990130    20200504    4
19990130    20200104    5
19990130    20180201    4
19990130    20170109    4
19990130    20160130    7
19990130    20250302    4
19990130    20180304    9
19990130    20160105    7
19990130    20190901    5
19990130    20100806    8
19990130    20201115    7
13450906    20120120    9
19990130    20010102    3
19990130    20190114    5
19990130    14220101    5
20040503    20020203    7
19000101    20170710    4
```

The result that I get (which is the sum of ALL NUMBER OF HOURS ADDED TOGETHER). Only interested in person 19990130's total number of hours:

```
select distinct PNr
              , sum(AntalTimmar) 
from Tidbok 
where PNr = 19990130 
group by PNr 
order by sum(AntalTimmar) = 1 desc;
```

Generates:

```
PNr         sum(NumberOfHours)
----------  ----------------
19990130    139
```

Comment: Show us how does your result looks like ? Also show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Posted a query that illustrates the undesired results that I obtain.

Comment: Edit the question add expected result too.

Comment: got it :) accepted your answer there since you first hehe :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is your column `AntalTimmar` you have stated you want to get the sum of NumberOfHours. This is done like this:

```
select pnr, sum(NumberOfHours)
from Tidbok
where pnr = '19990130';
```

Looks good to me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTTpJ9tTudkFrqy1WJghZj/5

Or is this what you are looking for:

```
select pnr, (select sum(t.NumberOfHours) from Tidbok t where t.pnr = '19990130')
from Tidbok
group by pnr;
```

The question at the beginning the is not so clear :)

[Here is the demo for the second query.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTTpJ9tTudkFrqy1WJghZj/6)

Comment: Got it, thanks!! sorry yeah antaltimmar is Swedish for Number of hours hehe

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `GROUP BY`, neither `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` or `DISTINCT`:

```
select PNr, sum(NumberOfHours) total
from Tidbok 
where PNr = 19990130
```

You would use `GROUP BY` if you wanted results for all PNRs.
Also since the query returns only 1 row there is no need for `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3NKQkwkZEP4ivJfCv4wNK2/0).
Results:

```
| PNr      | total |
| -------- | ----- |
| 19990130 | 139   |
```